# How do I get OS X 10.8.x to keep Finder windows open after a restart?

Tags: macos, finder

I just installed OS X 10.8.x on my Mac. An annoying thing I've discovered is that, whenever I restart the computer, it closes all the windows I have open in Finder. This is extremely annoying as I often have a large number of windows open to help me keep track of what I've been working on that day and need to back up. I check the "Reopen windows when logging back in" on the restart command but, as far as I can tell, it just reopens my applications, which isn't really what I'm looking for.

Comment: Worked in 10.7?

Comment: In `System Preferences -> General`, is there an option "Close windows when quitting an application"? What's it set to? That option is there on 10.9, but not sure about 10.8. I'm guessing you had it set to the wrong value. Note: system preferences will apply to *all* apps (that support the feature), while the posted answer will apply only to Finder. This means the setting will override the system wide setting just for the Finder app.

Answer (score 9):

Try unchecking System Preferences > General > Close windows when quitting an application. 10.7 restored the state of applications by default but 10.8 doesn't.

This enables restoring state in just Finder:

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool true
killall Finder
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how to implement the second part of your answer. I assume it's some sort of coding language. Where would I enter it into the system?

Comment: Just paste it to Terminal. You can find bundle identifiers of other applications with something like `osascript -e 'id of app "Safari"'`.

Comment: @third_aardvark if this answered your question please click the checkmark underneath the vote up/down arrows next to the answer to indicate that it solved your problem. For more information on how Ask Different and the StackExchange Q&A format works please see our [FAQ](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: Well, it clearly works after uncheck "Close windows when quitting an application" in General Preference Panel. __Although, isn't it a Bug or Product design flaw since everybody want all windows reopen after check the "Reopen windows when logging back in" when hitting the restart button?__ I gotta tell you man, this issue has bother me for quite long time, and finally figure out the right query for Google and got the answer.